# PHP_XLSXWriter_plus insert image into cell

Tags: php, excel

I´m using this library to create excel files.
Is there a way to insert an image into a cell,for example B1 with this library?
I haven´t found information about that.

Comment: While I'm not over-familiar with this specific library, it's worth noting that Excel doesn't have images "in" cells; they're actually "overlaid" at a particular position on the cell grid

Comment: Any alternative or some way to put the image?

Comment: The answer is "No" PHP XLSXWriter Plus doesn't support images at all